# How to pass selected row value to a button outside grid with parameter in v-data-table (vuetify)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-toolbar flat>
  <v-toolbar-title>Details</v-toolbar-title>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <v-col class="text-right">          
       <v-btn id="btnCopy" @click="Redirect()"   class="black--text">COPY</v-btn>            
    </v-col>
  </div>

  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
</v-toolbar>
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :value="selected"
  @input="enterSelect($event)"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="plist"
  :single-select="singleSelect"
  item-key="revId"
  show-select
  class="elevation-1"
  :single-expand="singleExpand"
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
  show-expand
  :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage"
  :page.sync="page"
  :loading="loadTable"
  loading-text="Loading data....Please wait"
>
```

//dynamically adding onclick event for the selected checkbox row in v-data-table grid
//in the below function values get all the values from the selected grid row but how to add parameter to the button?

without parameter im able to call button event but with parameter its not working?

```
enterSelect(values) {                                   
  var names = values.map( function(value) {                   
    var copyButton = document.getElementById('btnCopy');
    copyButton.setAttribute('onclick',  'Redirect');
  })
}
```

// this is the actual function called when clicked on btnCopy

```
 Redirect(revId) {
   alert("Hello"+this.value.revId);
  }
}
```

above is the v-data-table with checkboxes and when checked it's dynamically adding onclick event to a button which would eventually call function Redirect from a button by passing the parameter

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to add a new data property to hold the array of selected values, and then plug it into `@click` on the button

```js
data () {
  return {
    selectedRows: [],
  };
},
methods: {
  enterSelect(values) {
    this.selectedRows = values;
  },
}
```

```html
<v-btn id="btnCopy" @click="Redirect(selectedRows)"   class="black--text">COPY</v-btn>
```